# Unable to update appRoles in azure manifest

Tags: azure-active-directory

I'm unable to add new roles to my application manifest file in azure. Getting some random error

"Error detail: The client ID provided could not be found. [LLn0W]".

After some research, I came to know that only global/directory admins can update manifest file. My question is, why is it restricted to only admins? Why not enabled for application owners?

[image]

Comment: In my experience `Owners` assigned to an application are able to edit the application manifest and add roles.. i.e. you don't realy need to be a global administrator as you describe in your question here.. In fact the user I checked with has no directory role assigned to them at all. Only thing is that user is assigned as owner for application as you can see here https://i.stack.imgur.com/wNjn8.png

Comment: Also, in case of a different user who isn't an Admin or owner for application, the error message is quite intuitive and different than the one you have mentioned.. `Insufficient privileges to complete the operation` https://i.stack.imgur.com/WGdm2.png .. One important setting in my Azure AD is that all users can register applications.. which is default way for any new Azure AD tenant AFAIK.. Here is setting I'm referring to https://i.stack.imgur.com/h3shS.png.. Plz share the reference that talks about need to be global/directory admin? Also how are you updating manifest through code or portal?

Comment: Do click on "Mark as Answer" on the post that helps you and vote it as helpful, this can be beneficial to other community members.

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response. I'm still facing the same issue.

Comment: @SreekanthJagaleti Can you update the manifest by using the admin account? It seems your issue is not regarding the role. Can you paste the code which you added to the manifest?

Comment: I don’t have admin account

Comment: @SreekanthJagaleti never mind. Can you delete your changes to the manifest and add {
      "allowedMemberTypes": [
        "User"
      ],
      "displayName": "Test",
      "id": "c200e304-fff3-49f1-a4df-e406741ea680",
      "isEnabled": true,
      "description": "Bla bla",
      "value": "test"
    } to your appRoles to have a try?

Comment: I tried the same format

Comment: @SreekanthJagaleti If you delete the roles, can you save it? If you add the roles, what is the error message?

Comment: @TonyJu this is a brand new manifest and doestn't have any app roles in it. So cannot test delete and save.

Comment: @SreekanthJagaleti It is recommended to create a new application and try again. It is strange. I am the owner of my application, it works well on my side.

Answer (score 1):

> After some research, I came to know that only global/directory admins
>   can update manifest file.

If you are the owner of the app and not an admin in the Azure AD, you also have the privilege to edit the approle in the manifest. For normal users, not an owner or admin, they will have no sufficient privilege to make it.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

> My question is, why is it restricted to only admins? Why not enabled
>   for application owners?

If you are owner of the application, you are able to add new roles to your application manifest.

I am in my AD with User role.

[image]

When I try to edit the manifest of an application which I am not an owner of it. It told me that I do not have insufficient permission.

[image]

Then I use admin account grant me the owner role for this application. Now I can add approles successfully.

[image]